# Load only body on page change

Tags: angularjs

On my website i'm displaying the same header on each page and I wanted to know if there's an AngularJS / jQuery or simple JS solution to load only the content of the body and not the header on page change.

```
<html ng-app="headerApp" ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
  <head>
    <!-- here I load my JS and css ... -->
    <div ng-include="'templates/Header.tpl.html'"></div>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div ng-include="'templates/IndexBody.tpl.html'"></div>
   </body>
<footer><div ng-include="'templates/Footer.tpl.html'"></div>  </footer>
</html>
```

So my HTML looks like this I have separate template for each parts. But for now I create a html file for each pages. So I think there's a way to change the ng-include in the body.

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of the idea behind single page applications. Angular provides a built-in router that does this for you, and there is also the popular ui-router plugin.

You would change your view to:

```
<html ng-app="headerApp">
   <head ng-controller="HeaderCtrl">
    <div ng-include="'templates/Header.tpl.html'"></div>
   </head>
   <body>
     <div ng-view></div>
   </body>
   <footer><div ng-include="'templates/Footer.tpl.html'"></div>  </footer>
</html>
```

and configure the router in app.js:

```
angular.module('headerApp', ['ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider){
   $routeProvider.when('/', {
     templateUrl: 'templates/IndexBody.tpl.html',
     controller: 'IndexBodyCtrl'
   });
});
```

Note that you will need to include `angular-route.js` in your index.html. More reading here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Answer (score -1):

If it's an Angular app would you not use ng-view? Everything outside the view is the template and static as such. If you aren't building a spa then Angular probably isn't the best approach.

If it's Jquery then you could just do:

```
$("article").load('templatefiletoload.html');
```

beware that loading in your content like this is poor from an SEO point of view. Use server side includes if possible